# Scribe Tumblr Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Missing or invalid oauth_verifier.'

Tags: tumblr, scribe

I'm having problems with authenticating Tumblr using Scribe. I've followed an example that I found here on SO but I keep getting "org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Missing or invalid oauth_verifier.'"

Any ideas? Help would be GREATLY appreciated! Thanks.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import org.scribe.builder.api.TumblrApi;
import org.scribe.model.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private static OAuthService service;
    private Token requestToken;
    private Verifier verifier;
    private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info";
    private static Boolean authInProgress = false;
    public WebView TumblrWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if ( ! authInProgress ) {
            authInProgress = true;
            service = new ServiceBuilder()
                    .provider(TumblrApi.class)
                    .apiKey("xxx")
                    .apiSecret("yyy")
                    .callback("thisapp://tumblr")
                    .build();

            // Obtain the Request Token
            Log.d("Tumblr", "Fetching the Request Token...");
            requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
            Log.d("Tumblr", "Got the Request Token!");

            Log.d("Tumblr", "Now go and authorize Scribe here:");
            Log.d("Tumblr", ""+service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken) ));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (this.getIntent()!=null && this.getIntent().getData()!=null){
            Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith("thisapp://tumblr")) {
                verifier = new Verifier ( uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier") );
                // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
                requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
                Log.d("Tumblr", "Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
                Log.d("Tumblr", " ---> Request Token: " + requestToken.getToken());
                Log.d("Tumblr", " ---> Request Token Secret: " + requestToken.getSecret());
                Log.d("Tumblr", " ---> Verifier: " + verifier.getValue());
                Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                Log.d("Tumblr", "Got the Access Token!");
                Log.d("Tumblr", "(if you're curious it looks like this: " + accessToken + " )");

                // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
                Log.d("Tumblr", "Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
                OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
                service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
                Response response = request.send();
                Log.d("Tumblr", "Got it! Lets see what we found...");
                Log.d("Tumblr", ""+response.getBody());

                Log.d("Tumblr", "Thats it man! Go and build something awesome with Scribe! :)");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. This was caused because of different request token.

The way Tumblr's OAuth works:

- Your application requests for a `requestToken` and generates `AuthorizationUrl`.
- The user is redirected to tumblrs page for authentication.
- Once the user has granted all the permissions, tumblr redirects back to callback URL with `oauth_verifier` code.
- Now you try to generate `accessToken` based on `oauth_verifier` and `requestToken`.
- Now here is the twist, you need to make sure that the `requestToken` is same which was used while getting the URL, else it will throw an error as can't extract token.